# SonataUserBundle Symfony 3.1.7

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

Is it possible to user Symfony 3.1.7 + FosUserBundle 2.0dev AND SonataUserbundle 3.X ? I tried many installation but didn't get it.
I also googled the question but some says that Sonata only works with FOSuserBundle 1.3 which doesn't work with Symfony 3... :/

Any idea or workarround please?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just find the asnwer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461912/user-bundle-3-1-not-compatible-with-symfony-3-and-console-3-1) which is no we can't for the moment!!